# .NET PrintPreviewControl

Tags: .net, printing

I'm trying to use the PrintPreviewControl in .NET to display the print preview of my controls. I have a panel on the left with the settings (i.e. landscape, margins etc.). The user can update these and see the actual printout change as they do so (similar to Excel 2010 [here](http://news.office-watch.com/t/n.aspx?a=892)).

The only problem is

```
InvalidatePreview();
```

on the PrintPreviewControl invalidates all the pages, you get a dialog that says generating previews (doesn't look nice).

I'd like something like virtual paging in the DataGridView so that only the page displayed gets invalidated?

Does anyone know how I could do this with the PrintPreviewControl?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Have you ever solved the problem? A colleague of mine has this issue too and is looking for a solution.